# What, exactly, is a Flickr collection and why is it better than a set of sets?

Tags: flickr

This is what Flickr's [FAQs](http://www.flickr.com/help/collections/#237) have to say about collections:

> **How is a collection different than a set?**
>
> A set contains photos. A collection can contain sets (or other
>   collections).
>
> **Isn't this just sets of sets?**
>
> Yes, but no. It's better.

Can anyone clarify for me *why* it's better? I'm sure everyone uses them differently; I'm just having a hard time figuring out why you'd need them, and the FAQ is not exactly helpful.

Comment: Flickr seems to use the word "album" instead of "set" nowadays, although it's very confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If going deeper and wider is better, then that's why it's better. That's really all there is to it.

A collection can contain sets and other collections, going down as five (5) deep. That is you can have the following nests/groups:

> #### Animals collection
>
> - Four-legged set
> - Domestic pets set
> - Winged creatures collection
>
> #### Winged creatures collection
>
> - Pegasus set
> - Birds of prey set
>
> #### Edible collection
>
> - Animals collection
> - Winged creatures collection

Think of them like Gmail labels. An email can have multiple labels as can Flickr sets/collections be in more than one collection.

It's a superset of another way to organise your Flickr photos.

Comment: Unicorns don't have wings; you're possibly thinking of Pagasuses (pagasim?). Which, however, are notoriously camera-shy, and lack horns.

Comment: Correct, was thinking of the Pegasus type beast